# How to perform group by in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, group-by

I need to read data from an excel file and perform group by on the data after that. 
 
the structure of the data is like following:

```
n c
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

I need to read these data and then generate a list of dictionaries based on the c value. 
desired output would be a list of dictionaries with c as keys and values of n as values like this:

```
[{1:[3]}, {2:[1,3]}, {3:[1,2,3]}, {4:[1,2]}, {5:[2]}]
```

I use this function to read data and it works fine:

```
data = pandas.read_excel("pathtofile/filename.xlsx", header=None)
```

Comment: OT: why a list of dictionaries, instead of just a single dictionary with all these keys together?

Comment: This output structure is an input for another function. but a single dictionary with all these keys is fine too. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
d1 = df.groupby('c')['n'].agg(list).to_dict()
res = [{k:v} for k,v in d1.items()]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{1: [3]}, {2: [1, 3]}, {3: [1, 2, 3]}, {4: [1, 2]}, {5: [2]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample output `dict`

```
d=df.groupby('c').n.agg(list).to_dict()
{1: [3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2, 3], 4: [1, 2], 5: [2]}
```